# Subtract two unbalanced DataFrames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isnull

I have two unbalanced DataFrames and would like to create a third by subtracting values to get the delta between them. Here's an example of the three dataframes. I would like to take CURRENT, subtract corresponding EXPECTED to get DELTA. This works as expected and I produce the correct results in DELTA when values in CURRENT and EXPECTED exist. However, when they don't exist, I get NaN in DELTA. When I would like it to be as below:

```
      CURRENT
      Region1    Region2
type1   5          3
type2   2          11
type3   7          1

      EXPECTED
      Region1    Region2
type1   15         1
type2   6          4

      DELTA
      Region1    Region2
type1   -10        2
type2   -4         7
type3   7          1
```

With my current code, the type3 row in DELTA is NaN, NaN.

```
def get_delta(self, CURRENT, EXPECTED):
    delta = CURRENT
    delta['Region1'] = current[['Region1']] - \
                              expected[['Region1']]
    delta['Region2'] = current[['Region2']] - \
                              expected[['Region2']]
    return delta
```

I have tried checking to see if delta.isnull() or delta.empty but that doesn't work. Essentially I would like to treat any nonexisting value in EXPECTED as a 0, and then just do the subtraction CURRENT - RESERVED to get DELTA. I guess I could do this by treating any NaN as 0, or by filling in missing rows into EXPECTED with the proper rows/indices as 0.

I tried:

```
new_df = pd.concat([CURRENT, EXPECTED], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

and then subtracting from there, but when I try the concat I get an error "ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (0,13) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,13)" so not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
DELTA = CURRENT.sub(EXPECTED, fill_value=0)
print (DELTA)
       Region1  Region2
type1    -10.0      2.0
type2     -4.0      7.0
type3      7.0      1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed and allowed me to remove a whole delta function from my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reindex`

```
In [217]: CURRENT - EXPECTED.reindex(CURRENT.index, fill_value=0)
Out[217]:
       Region1  Region2
type1      -10        2
type2       -4        7
type3        7        1
```

---

Details

```
In [218]: CURRENT
Out[218]:
       Region1  Region2
type1        5        3
type2        2       11
type3        7        1

In [219]: EXPECTED
Out[219]:
       Region1  Region2
type1       15        1
type2        6        4
```